# Get the title of an <img> and apply it to it's parent <div> with YUI3

Tags: javascript, yui, parent, yui3

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="source.com/image.jpg" title="My Image">
</div>
```

I would like to get the title of all images ("My image") in this case, and add this title on to the parent , so that the above example would look like this:

```
<div title="My Image">
    <img src="source.com/image.jpg" title="My Image">
</div>
```

Would appreciate it very much if someone could give me a push in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: `element.parentNode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much the same question as the previous one you posted. In this case you do need to save the image node to a variable so that you can read its title and set it to the parent.

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
  var image = Y.one('img');
  image.get('parentNode').set('title', image.get('title'));
});
```

If you're having trouble making changes to DOM elements I'd suggest you take a little time to read a couple of articles/books that introduce you to the subject. Here are some good options:

- [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net). A great book for starting with JavaScript and that has [a chapter about the DOM](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter12.html).
- The Mozilla Developer Network has [a great collection of articles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM).
- The [YUI3 Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449304192) will give you everything you need to get started with YUI.

Comment: Thanks juan, i had an idea but was having trouble with the variable bit. Thanks for the resource links, too.